# Difference between Laravel Mail vs swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, swiftmailer

This is probably a stupid question but I am using Laravel 4.2. I am using Laravel to send emails and I know Laravel comes with SwiftMailer. If I am calling Mail::send like the codes below, am I calling SwiftMailer's Mail library or am I calling PHP's Mail library? So, what's the diferrence the two?

app/config/mail.php

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'from' => array('address' => 'my_gmail_username.gmail.com', 'name' => 'Test Email'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'my_gmail_username',
    'password' => 'my_gmail_password',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

app/routes.php

```
namespace MyMail;    
use Mail;

Mail::send('mail_template1', array('name' => 'Laravel'), function($message) use ($arr_index)
            {
                $message->to('name@email.com', 'name')
                        ->from('different_email@gmail.com', 'Another name')
                        ->subject('Laravel Email Test 1');  
            });
```

Comment: Mail::send is just a laravel wrapper for swift mailer, so you are calling swift mailer when doing that call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Laravel provides a clean, simple API over the popular SwiftMailer library.

And about the php mail:

> If you wish to use the PHP mail function to send mail, you may change the driver to mail in the configuration file.

Mail::send is just a laravel wrapper for swift mailer, so you are calling swift mailer when doing that call unless you change `'driver' => 'smtp'` to `'driver' => 'mail'`, only then will it use the PHP's mail.

Reference: [Laravel Mail Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/mail)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I see some people using $message = Swift_Message::newInstance(). So I thought I am calling to PHP's Mail library unless I declare it that way.